# How to get id (not clientId) of client in keycloak?

Tags: client, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

When creating a new client in Keycloak service through sending the post request to `/{realm}/clients`, both `clientId` and `id` are optional fields in post body.

If I didn't specify them, keycloak will generate it automatically. Then I found when I request to get `client-secret`, I need to put the `id` into url to indicate the `client-secret` of which client I need to get ?

I try to figure out how can I get the `id` of client from Keycloak API docs but didn't get the answer.
Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from following endpoint calls.

> I try to figure out how can I get the id of client from Keycloak API
> docs but didn't get the answer.

To get the `id` you can call the endpoint `/{realm}/clients` with the parameter `clientID` for instance using curl:

```
curl -k -X GET $KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/clients?clientId=$CLIENT_ID \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

The `$ACCESS_TOKEN` is the access token from a token omitted on behalf of a user with the proper privileges (*e.g.,* admin).

From the response .json you extract id (*e.g.,*  jq -r .[0].id). In my personal [Git repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/tree/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Clients) you can find a script to extract the client secret.

**Assigning the proper user permissions**

For those that do not want to get an access token from the master admin user, you can get it from another user but that user needs the permission `view-clients` from the `realm-management` client. For that you can:

**(OLD Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- In `client roles` select `realm-management`
- Select the role `view-clients` and click on `Add selected`

[image]

**(New Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- Click on `Assign role`
- In `Search by role name` type `view-clients`
- Select the role and assign it

[image]

Comment: "From the response .json you extract id" - is there no way to do that with a query parameter instead? I can't find any docs on `q` or `search`.

Comment: Hi as far as I am aware no

Answer (score 2):

It's also worth mentioning that clients have to be assigned to `view-clients` role.

In my case I set it up in `Service Account Roles` tab of `admin-cli` client:

- `Client Roles` > `realm-management`